# Why do I need to make this non friend == operator overload a member function to avoid "undefined reference" errors?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, undefined-reference, linkage

I have the following class, it is defined like so:

```
namespace ns{
class Bit{
public:
    explicit Bit(bool bit);
    Bit() = default;
    explicit operator bool () const;
    [[nodiscard]]
    bool value() const;
    [[nodiscard]]
    Bit operator==(const Bit& rhs) const;
    //friend Bit operator==(const Bit &lhs, const Bit &rhs); also doesn't work
private:
    bool m_bit;
};
//doesn't work
//[[nodiscard]]
//Bit operator==(const Bit &lhs, const Bit &rhs);
}
```

When I define the operator == overload as a standalone function, it doesn't work, I get

```
undefined reference to `ns::operator==(ns::Bit const&, ns::Bit const&)'
```

Similar story for the friend function version.

The definition of the standalone function is as follows in the .cpp file:

```
ns::Bit operator==(const ns::Bit &lhs, const ns::Bit &rhs) {
    return ns::Bit(lhs.value() == rhs.value());
}
```

The definition of the member function, which works, is as follows

```
ns::Bit ns::Bit::operator==(const ns::Bit &rhs) const{
    return Bit(value() == rhs.value());
}
```

Why am I being forced to make a member function?

Comment: You prototype `ns::operator==` (in the ns namespace) but define `::operator==` (global namespace).

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? switching it to your "doesn't work" version, it compiles for me and `int main() { ns::Bit a,b; if(a==b) return 1; return 0;}` wants to call the friend function.

Comment: @jhill read my post, it says why  it doesn't work, 1201ProgramAlarm has it right. If you tried the code I used, it shouldn't work for you (maybe you are defining the operator in the global namespace?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Okay, wow, that's exactly it, my IDE normally fixes these sorts of things, but apparently doesn't handle auto generation of stand-alone operator definitions well.  If you write an answer describing what the problem is I would gladly mark it as correct and upvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ns::Bit ns::operator==(const ns::Bit &lhs, const ns::Bit &rhs) {
  return ns::Bit(lhs.value() == rhs.value());
}
```

you prototyped `ns::operator==` then defined `::operator==`.

Only `ns::operator==` is found via ADL.  `::operator==` may also be found depending on what other `==` operators and what namespace you are in, adding confusion.

Comment: Alternatively: `namespace ns { Bit operator==(const Bit &lhs, const Bit &rhs) { return Bit(lhs.value() == rhs.value()); } }`